# how do i add x number of months to current date in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to add x amount of months to current date in angular2 but i'm find difficulty in doing it, i'm able to get the current date formatted in a way i want but its left with adding the x amount of number to the current month.

JS

```
 this.send_date=new Date();
 this.formattedDate=new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
 console.log(this.formattedDate);
```

For example if i had 5 months to the current month, the date should change to `2018-04-09`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use setMonth() method in javascript

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
   send_date=new Date();
   formattedDate : any;
   constructor(){
     this.send_date.setMonth(this.send_date.getMonth()+8);
     this.formattedDate=this.send_date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
 console.log(this.formattedDate); 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want this by JS

You can use that:
`new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + yourMonth))`

for your case:
`new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + 5))`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you tu use `moment.js` library to do that. It's a good library to manage date, dateTime and format to display.

An quick example to answer your problem :

```
var date = moment(); // now
var dateIn5Months = date.add(5, 'months'); // now + 5 months
var strDate = dateIn5Months.format('YYYY-MM-dd');
```

And the result :
[image]

More details here "[moment.js doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/)"